# Why my Apache is not serving images or relative content?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, web-server

I have a server at: `www.patagoniatrabaja.com.ar`

I've a cake installation at `www.patagoniatrabaja.com.ar/cake/` to test the CSS.

I'm setting up a server and installed Apache. The problem is that it's not serving any image or relative content. I've changed things in the Apache configuration. I'll paste it here:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/cake">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It was moved to Webmasters since they also do apache over there, especially .htaccess stuff, which it sounded like it was all about. This includes much more information, thank you.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. No one answered there though.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters to the issue you're experiencing but I'm not seeing a closing </html> tag

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting "Not Found" or "Permission Denied"?  Check your error_log for Apache and the HTML source for the served pages.  What is the browser being told to ask for? You may need to add one or more alias entries to the config if your static content lives outside of the /var/www/cake path. While I enjoy eating cake, I have yet to use CakePHP.  Frameworks often have their own little rules to watch for, so make sure you have configured any "base folder" options or the like.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well... After shifting around some content (in terms of where it was in the folder structure) and restarting apache I was able to get to serve images & dynamic (php driven) content. I think the problem was the the linking formats which I had used coming from windows.